# jQGrid columns goes outside of grid when it re-sizing manually

Tags: jqgrid

Am facing a design issue when re sizing the column headers as below,
[image: sdsdsenter image description here]
Here is the code i use , can anyone please advise me if am wrong ?

```js
jQuery("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid({
    data:dataArray,
    datatype: "local",
    shrinkToFit: true,
    height: 500,
    width: 900,
    rowheight: 160,
    colNames: ['User', 'IP Address', 'Registered Contacts'],
    colModel: [{ name: 'UserLinePort', width: 520, index: 'UserLinePort', stype: 'text', sortable: true },
           { name: 'SourceIP', index: 'SourceIP', width: 130, editable: true, stype: 'text', sortable: true                 },
           { name: 'registeredcontact', index: 'registeredcontact', width: 190, editable: true, sortable: true },
                                ],
    rowNum: 30,
    rowList: [30, 50, 100],
    pager: '#jQGridDemoPager',
    loadComplete: function () {
        stopLoadingIcon();
    }
});
```

Comment: **which version of jqGrid you use?**. I'm not sure what problem exactly you have. I suppose that your program will be solved by upgrading to more recent version of jqGrid. I fixed some problems with resizing in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) - it's the fork which I develop. Try to resize any column of the grid or the grid itself on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/navButtons0-fa4.htm)

Comment: I am using version 4.5.1.

Comment: You don't described your existing problem clear enough. The version 4.5.1 works like you already know. **One can't change the existing behavior in jqGrid 4.5.1 using some additional options.** The only way consist from the usage of *another version*. Do you tried the demo, which I posted? Is the problem with resizing still exist? You can test free jqGrid in your application if you just change the URLs to jqGrid files to [the following](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs).

Comment: I will check and update the results, thank for the info.

Comment: I set the free jqGrid links in my applications and seems fine with column re sizing. So in 4.5.1 we cannot do this , please advise. Am just a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

jqGrid 4.5.1 is relatively old version. After publishing 4.7.1 short after publishing 4.7 and renaming jqGrid to [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) with changing license agreement and prices (see [the post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438)), I started alternative fork of jqGrid: [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) which features are described in the readmes to every published version and in [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki).

I rewrote many places of old jqGrid code. For example I rewrote the large part of column resizing and have changes the resizing of the grid. You can see on [the demo](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs) for example how the resizing works now.

**One can't change the existing behavior in jqGrid 4.5.1 using some additional options**. You can test the current behavior of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) (the current version is 4.10.0) and [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) (the current version is 5.0.1) and choose, which one corresponds more to your requirements. You can see on [the demo site](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/) how Guriddo jqGrid JS works.